# Gradient border around popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I'm working on a HTML implementation of the Office Ribbon to use in Web Apps.
Here's a screenshot that shows you:

[image]

You see that I have a DropDown on the ribbon under "New Items". So far so good, but let's compare it against the real Office implementation:

[image]

Here you see that the dropdown menu has a gradient around it that makes makes it's clear that it's laying on top of the interface.

Now I cannot accomplish then so I was hoping someone can given me a solution to this issue.

The HTML for the dropdown element is as following:

```
<div class="icon bigicon">
    <img src="Resources/Icons/MailNewItemMenu.png" />
    <div class="label">
        New<br/>Items
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menucontents">
            <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0px;">
                <li style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px; text-align: left;">Create</li>
                <li style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px; text-align: left;">Manage</li>
                <li style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px; text-align: left;">Delete</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css is as follows:

```
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon { text-align: center; display: inline-block; padding-top: 2px; padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; vertical-align: top; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .bigicon { height: 70px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .smallicon { padding-top: 0px; height: 24px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon:hover { background-color: #cde6f7; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon:active { background-color: #92C0E0; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon .label { line-height: 16px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .smallicon { display: inline-block; padding-right: 5px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .smallicon IMG { vertical-align: middle; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .smallicon .label { display: inline-block; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon .menu { position: relative; top: -1px; left: 1px; }
#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon .menu .menucontents { position: relative; z-index: 100; background-color: white; left: -4px; border-top: 1px solid #C6C6C6; border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C6C6; background-image: linear-gradient(#C6C6C6, #C6C6C6), linear-gradient(#C6C6C6, #C6C6C6); background-size:1px 100%;     background-position: 0 0, 100% 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: You could use `box-shadow` for this. Two things: 1. don't use inline styles, because you are unnecessarily repeating the same thing 2. why are you writing selectors that are miles long? This is not very effective and should be avoided. Write the minimal selector that is enough to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To make a couple of things right, I'm just doing the best I can to recreate the Office Ribbon but I'm not a slicer. I'm going with what I know and what I find on the internet. So that's the reason why I'm using inline styles and mile long selectors.

I'm still searching for people who whans to help me on this project by forking the Github Repo and change the HTML, CSS and eventually the javascript to clean it up. I'm just trying to make it work in all major browsers.

What do you advice to use instead of inline-block? Float: left? And minimal selectors, 1 class then?

Comment: So now you found something useful on the internet ;). I suggest you take the advice and your project will be much more cleaned up already. What do you mean by major browsers by the way?

Comment: I mean latest versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome. Btw, what do you mean with minimal CSS selectors (it means 1 class if possible, if multiple classes with the same name, use the previous element as well, is that correct?

Comment: [`box-shadow` is supported since IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow). And yes, I mean the minimal possible selector. For example, use `.ribbon .icon`. It means an icon somewhere in the ribbon. Make the selector more specific if needed, but start from the minimum. Drop `#OfficeUI` id selector - it limits you to only one instance of your stuff, because you can only use an id once in a document.

Comment: Thanks, I've achieved in making it looks nice. Could you just take some time to answer my previous question so I can clean up the project?

Comment: Already edited into my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for making that clear. About display: inline-block, what do you advice then? Float: left?

Comment: There is no problem with `display: inline-block`. By inline styles, I mean `style=""` attributes in your HTML. You should avoid using them.

Comment: I'm working on removing them, those are there to test the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow). It is [supported since IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow).